# Forcing sunflower plot to start at x=0

Tags: r

When creating a sunflower plot for logistic regression, the x-axis starts at 2. Can I change this behaviour to make the x-axis start at 0? I've already tried to manually change this by changing the x-axis, but that didn't make x=0 visible (see #c1).

The Sunflower Plot Image as it currently is, starting at x=2;

[image]

```r
# EE contains the Likert Scale values
EE.min <- min(EE)
EE.max <- max(EE)
EE.x <- seq(EE.min, EE.max, length = 500)
New.EE <- data.frame(EE = EE.x)

# Creating prediction
EE.p <- predict(logit, New.EE, type = "response")
sunflowerplot(EE, cb, main = "Effort Expectancy",
              xlab= "EE (5-point Likert-Scale)", ylab="Likelihood", yaxt="n", xaxt="n")

# c1:
axis(1, at = seq(0,5,0.5), labels = c(0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5 , 3, 3.5, 4, 4.5, 5), las=1)
axis(2, at = seq(0,1,0.2), labels = c("No = 0", 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, "Yes = 1"), las = 2)
abline(h = seq(0,1,0.2), lty = 2)
lines(EE.x, EE.p)
```

Comment: Questions should include complete test cases.  The input here is missing.  See the info at the top of the [tag:r] tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sunflowerplot` has an argument `xlim` for the limits of the x axis.

Compare

```
sunflowerplot(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Sepal.Width)
```

to

```
sunflowerplot(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Sepal.Width, xlim = c(0, 20))
```